# how to work with cross domain cookie or session in java

Tags: java, pdk

I am using pdk jdeveloper portlet.

I have deployed ear on tomcat server with host `www.test1.com:8080/`

now i m using it's provider on oracle server with same host but different port like `www.test1.com:9090/`

so here i m not able to use cookie or session thing on `www.test1.com:9090/`

I have set cookie using javascript as below:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

setCookie("USER","test",365);
```

now tried to get this cookie on portlet page as below.

```
 PortletRenderRequest pReq = (PortletRenderRequest)
    request.getAttribute(HttpCommonConstants.PORTLET_RENDER_REQUEST);
    try 1: Cookie[] cookies =request.getCookies(); // get null
    try 2: Cookie[] cookies = (Cookie[])pReq.getCookies(); // get null
```

how can i achieve this ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a domain on cookie. [link](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm), This gives you a good start. I read this article and found that its easy to share cookie across sub domain but  complicated to share it across different domain. This would also be useful [link](http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/892166-cross-domain-cookies)